# WireShark to capture Android device network packets

Tags: android, macos, wireshark

I need to connect my Android App to send data to com score each time the app is launched.
Comscore suggested to use WireShark to capture the network data.
I installed the Wireshark but How to I capture my Android device connected to my MAC. Also my MAC is connected through ethernet cable for network connection

I selected Option -> Capture in Wireshark but after that I don't see my device listed in it

Comment: Most likely you need to do your capturing on a system through which the device's network traffic is flowing, then use a *filter* to select packets corresponding to the device.  Most Android devices do not support getting their network connection through the USB cable - though emulators of course get it from the hosting system.  More likely you would need to use a wireless access point as the interception device, either a hardware one capable of running wireshark/tcpdump, or else a wire-to-wireless connection-sharing type of setup on your desktop.

Comment: How to do wire-to-wireless connection-sharing type on my mac to my android device. My Mac is connected thru ethernet

Comment: You'd probably need to ask about that on some Mac power user site; it's not really a development question.  If you can run your app on the emulator, that is likely the easiest way to investigate this.

Comment: In WireShark when I gave the filter to http.host=="b.scorecardresearch.com", I don't see the exact hostname, but I see an ipaddress in the destination. It means it is correctly tracked. or WireShark is displaying some other network traffic data

Comment: I was able to see the packet transferred in emulator… Thank you